# Why do you need to use clearInterval to reset the timer in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following code:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

Why do you need to return a cleanup function that resets the interval object? In my understanding, since the `interval` function object was not created with `useCallback()`, the function should be re-initialized with each render and therefore have no memory of past interval values. Why is a cleanup function needed to clear it before the next render?

Comment: The component will have no memory of past intervals but they will still be running in the browser, that's exactly why you need to clear them on component unmount

Comment: I see, clearInterval() sends a message to the browser API telling it to stop executing the async function. Thanks!

Comment: I've made a little example that shows what happens if you don't clear the interval: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kdyxjz?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: So as I understand it, several equivalent function objects are created all with closure around the same `count` state variable. For each toggle, a new callback function object that increments this variable is created and sent to the browser. Without `clearInterval()`, the browser is never told to kill the last callback function upon the component being unmounted and it keeps incrementing the `count` variable.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is a cleanup function needed to clear it *before the next render*?

(emphasis mine)

It's not and it's not what this code does.

By passing an empty dependency list to `useEffect` (`[]`) you are effectively telling React to only run this hook the *first time* the component renders, not(!) every time the component re-renders.

Now, clearing the interval when the component gets unmounted/destroyed (which is what this  code does) *is necessary*, otherwise the interval would keep running (and throw an error eventually since you cannot update the state of an unmounted component).

Comment: After the component is unmounted why does the interval object still exist?

Comment: There isn't really an "interval object". With `setInterval` you are telling the JavaScript engine: "execute this function ever so often" and you get back an ID that identifies this "job". The engine doesn't know anything about the code that created the interval. All it knows it that it was instructed to execute the interval. So when it's time to stop it it's the responsibility of the developer to inform the engine about that.